# azure api management soap to rest feature

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I'm trying to expose my SOAP service as REST using azure API management SOAP to REST feature.

The WS imports, exposes my services and works fine, but all generated REST services are exposed with POST verb. When i try to change to verb GET the method GetUsers, for example, the content does not load (I receive an OK, but without content). When i try keeping the method with the POST verb, the content loads.

Is this possible? Can i change a HTTP verb from a originally SOAP service that was exposed as REST using Azure Management API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to resolve that by adding set-method policy, so that when APIM receives GET request it changes method to POST before forwarding it to backend.

Comment: In addition to changing the method, if the operation requires a simple set of parameters that could be added as query or path parameters, you will have to add transformations likely using liquid to generate the corresponding soap envelope accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your API Management policy

```
<set-method>POST</set-method>
```